# Range of phase difference

Tags: waves, wavefunction, mathematics

Is there a particular range in which the phase difference between two waves must be specified? For example, here;

[image]
apparently you can only say E lags behind I by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and not that I lags behind E by $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$. This confusion wouldn't come up if phase difference was a quantity confined to values between 0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I haven't seen it defined that way anywhere. I know both are similar, mathematically speaking, but it gets messier when you're doing the actual physics, like if you're asked which wave lags the other.

Comment: it is indeed rarely defined, but in my field, phase difference is usually in the range from -$\pi$ to $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> . . . . apparently you can only say E lags behind I by $\frac{\pi}{2}$  . . . .

This statement is incorrect on two counts.

The first is that actually E **leads** I by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Note that whatever $E$ does, $I$ does later in time, so $I$ lags behind $E$..

The second is that there are an infinite number of ways the phase difference can be stated.
What often happens is that the phase difference is limited to a range of angles eg $-\pi \le \text{phase difference} \le \pi$ or $0 \le \text{phase difference} \le \pi$  or $-\frac \pi 2 \le \text{phase difference} \le \frac \pi 2$  or $0 \le \text{phase difference} \le \pi$.

From you graph and without any further information one could also say that E **leads** I by $\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer or I **leads** E by $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2n\pi$.

Comment: Ok, so phase difference isn't really a fixed value between any two waves, and mathematically, it can be anything. Furthermore, like you said, the actual physical phenomena that the graphs represent can also have some effect on the definition-as in voltage being the instigator of current. This's also what I thought, but this type of question has been asked on tests, with single-correct options. I guess even then you can't really pick one value, can you?

Comment: Usually, if it is a multiple choice type question, there is only one correct answer and if the setter has done their job properly no ambiguities! For your graph I would expect the answer to be $\pi/2$.

Comment: The question asks about which lags the other... Which is kind of ambiguous, right?

Comment: For lagging just reverse the labels of the waves.